# Records updated in Compass keep reverting

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I have a MongoDB instance hosted on AWS DocumentDB.  There is only one node in the replica set, and this is MongoDB 4.0.0 Community edition.

Twice now I've updated records in Compass and clicked the "Update" button.  I've confirmed that the change was made.  A few hours later, the change reverts.

From my research, this is typically caused by a MongoDB rollback.  But everything I've read says that rollbacks typically occur when the secondary databases associated with a replica set are out of sync with the primary.  But I don't have secondary databases.

Can anyone provide any insight - I'm not sure where else to look or what else to research.

Edit to add:  Also, is this likely to be a hosting problem (AWS DocumentDB) or a database problem directly?

Answer (score 0):

All writes on Amazon DocumentDB are durable, write concern majority by default and can't be changed. There's also no rollback mechanism that would cause the database server to revert to a previous state. You must have other client or application that is making other update and changing the document.
Try enabling the profiler, or, probably better, enable change streams and watch the changes to identify what's making the change.